# Does std::addressof negate the STL operator& requirement?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

In order for a type to "play nicely" with the C++03 Standard Libraries, it was considered a bad idea to overload the `operator&()` since the address was need to correctly use the type and overloading it created unexpected problems; classic example here is `ATL::CComBSTR`.

- With the advent of `std::addressof()` in C++11 and on, does this negate that old requirement(s) on the types being used in the standard library?
- Is the requirement explicitly stated in (or removed from) the standard in C++11, i.e. is the standard library mandated by the specification to use `std::addressof()`?

Comment: What 'requirement' in C++03? Are you sure it was a *requirement* and not a *recommendation*?

Comment: What is wrong with CComBSTR?

Comment: @Rapptz, true, I'm not sure it was mandated as a requirement, but if overloaded on `operator&` the type and the STL didn't make good "bed fellow".

Comment: @MattMcNabb, it overloaded the `operator&`

Comment: "that containers require their elements to be CopyConstructible and Assignable (C++03 23.1/3), and being CopyConstructible requires that &t return a T * that is the address of t (20.1.3/1)"

Comment: Overloading unary `operator&` makes you a bad programmer, regardless of whether or not your code works with the STL.

Comment: That cited requirement is no longer there in C++11, which means that the container must tolerate types that overload `operator &` with `std::addressof` or a similar mechanism.

Comment: I see nothing in C++11 17.6.3 that indicates `operator &` is even considered, much less some expectation of mandated behavior, for CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable. Take that as you will.

Comment: (FWIW, with GCC/C++11 `std::map` and `vector` at ideone.com I didn't observe problems with overridden `operator&` - e.g. http://ideone.com/RyA6Hp)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `CComBSTR` (and other smart pointer wrappers) override `operator&` to return the pointer being held. The reasoning being that a smart pointer should act like a real pointer as much as possible to minimize code changes needed to migrate to use of smart pointers. So, for example, given a variable `CComBSTR bstr;`, calling `&bstr` would return a `BSTR*`, not a `CComBSTR*` as some people may expect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, but I wasn't aware that this was considered a problem until now

Comment: @MattMcNabb: probably not so much with typical `CComBSTR` usage. But one area where this has bitten me time and time again is Borland's `WideString` class, which is similar to `CComBSTR` and also overrides `operator&`. Makes it near impossible to pass a `WideString` to a function that takes a `WideString*` as a parameter (the same problem exists for `CComBSTR`) without using a dynamic allocation. No such problem with Borland's other string classes, which do not override `operator&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value_type` of a container only has a few requirements. They depend mainly on the container, but for the general case the requirements are at the very least `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`.

Looking at the C++11 standard tables for what these requirements mean, you get this:

§ 17.6.3.1 Table 20 (`MoveConstructible`):

```
 +----------------------------------------------------------+
 | Expression         |       Post Condition                |
 |----------------------------------------------------------+
 | T u = rv;          | u is equivalent to the              |
 |                    | value of rv before the construction |
 +----------------------------------------------------------+
 | T u(rv);           | T(rv) is equivalent to the          |
 |                    | value of rv before the construction |
 +----------------------------------------------------------+
 | rv's state is unspecified.                               |
 |                                                          |
 +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

§ 17.6.3.1 Table 22 (`MoveAssignable`).

```
  +-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
  | Expression|  Return Type | Return value| Post Condition       |
  |-----------|--------------|-------------|----------------------|
  | t = rv;   |  T&          | t           | t is equivalent to   |
  |           |              |             | the value of rv      |
  |           |              |             | before the assignment|
  |           |              |             |                      |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
  | rv's state is unspecified                                     |
  |                                                               |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are more requirements given to a container depending on what it is, like `DefaultConstructible`. However, neither of the requirements require `operator&` to not be overloaded. They mainly deal with the constructibility of the `value_type` rather than the operator overloads provided by the type.

You can find the other tables over at § 17.6.3.1. The container requirements are specified over at § 23.

Answer (score 5):

The **C++03 CopyConstructible** requirements explicitly included the requirement that the address-of operator returned the actual address of the object, as noted in the comments § 20.1.3 (Table 30), hence types that overloaded that operator could run into problems with the Standard Library.

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| expression | return type | requirement              |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| T(t)       |             | t is equivalent to T(t)  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| T(u)       |             | u is equivalent to T(u)  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| t.~T()     |             |                          |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| &t         | T*          | denotes the address of t |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| &u         | const T*    | denotes the address of u |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

**C++11 simplifies the move (and copy constructible and assignable definitions)** to a more basic syntax;

```
T ( rvalue ); // move construct
T u = rvalue; // move assign
T ( value ); // copy construct
T u = value; // copy assign
```

It makes no mention of the overloaded address of operator, but it also make little mention of `std::addressof` explicitly being required (outside some `.resize()` functions). `std::allocator` does however explicitly require the address of the types to be correct even in the presence of overloaded `operator&()`.

In conclusion, there may be little in the specification to mandate the use of `std::addressof()` but in light of the simplified requirements and explicit object address requirements; the use of `std::addressof()` (or similar) is very close to being mandated.

My take-away here is; if you are writing **generic code and require the address of an object, use `std::addressof()`** and stick to being on the safe side.

Comment: Highlighting the differences between C++03 and C++11 here.